# What is the equivalent of GetEncoding("28591") of C# in Python?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, serial-port

I want to get the code of a device from COM6, I easily get the output from C# using the code below:

```
serialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

but I don't know how to do it in Python.

I already tried:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port='COM6'
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.timeout=2

if ser.is_open:
    ser.close()
else:
    ser.open()
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)


while True:
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    data_raw = (ser.readline())
    print(data_raw.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: this table should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=netframework-4.7.2. `28591` is the code number for `iso-8859-1`, so you can tell python to decode with that specific encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pythonnet to access .Net libraries. When I run the below code I get System.Text.Latin1Encoding

```
import clr

from System import Text

result = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
print(result)
```

More here - https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: I can't access System, it tells me that the reference is unresolves

Comment: @DanialSa'adati Did you install pythonnet? See the diff installation option here. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation. The option that worked for me was the last option (unofficial binaries)

(download pythonnet‑2.4.0.dev0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl)

pip install pythonnet‑2.4.0.dev0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: yes, I did install both pythonnet 2.3 and clr using pip, Pycharm doesn't even offer "System" and "Text". Thank you for allocating your time.

Comment: @DanialSa'adati Uninstall clr from pip. It is weird but clr namespace comes from when you install pythonnet. (clr from pip install is something totally different.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it.

Comment: unfortunately nothing!